How to fix a maximum time exceeded on an email script
Background:
I'm using a minutes-timer script to send emails when a record is selected. Names and emails are appended into a requests page. The script scrolls through any names on the list. For any names where the "Notified" field is blank, it composes an email with some customized text, then adds a Notified memo in the spreadsheet field. The next time the script runs, it skips emailing that person.
The script runs every 10 minutes. This is for two reasons: (a) I want the users to have a minute or two to cancel things if they request the wrong name by mistake, and (b) I don't want to slow down the system further with an installable on-edit trigger, when it already has other on-edit functions that consume resources.
Problem:
I have a number of different spreadsheets all using the same setup, one for each user. Every day, I'm getting error message reports from many of those sheets, giving me "Maximum time exceeded" errors on the script.
I don't know why that would be in the first place, unless it's too many scripts running at once. That aside, the script is fairly short, there are never more than 40 records on the requests page tab at a time, and most of the time far less; in fact, many times, the error happens when there are no records to search at all, such as in the middle of the night or on weekends.
I want to keep notifications on in case the script produces a permanent error, but I frankly don't care if it fails once in a while; it will still send the next time. I'm getting overwhelmed by the error messages, though.
Desired solution:
I want to either fix the code to improve the run-time performance of the script and avoid that errors, or else find out if there's a way to add a line of code to time-out the script without generating a spreadsheet script error report.
Coding:
The email function is as follows:
function SendEmail2() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Dumbledore requests page');
var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
var subject = "Detention appointment";
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
var email = data[i][9]; // Email address from Column J
var notifiedStatus = data[i][10]; // Status from Column K
    if (email && !notifiedStatus) { 
      var studentName = data[i][0];
      var teacherName = data[i][3];
      var homeTeacher = data[i][2];
      var message = "Hello " + studentName + ",<br><br>This email is to inform you that you have a detention with one of your professors (" + teacherName + "), during your next free period. Check in with your free period supervisor (" + homeTeacher + ") immediately after your lunch, or your substitute teacher if there is one, then go straight to " + teacherName + "'s room as soon as you're told to do so.<br><br>Thank you.<br><br>Sincerely,<br>the Hogwarts Spreadsheet";
      var replyTo = "dumbledore_a@hogwarts.ed.uk"; // Reply-to email address
  MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: email,
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: message,
        replyTo: replyTo
      });
  sheet1.getRange(i + 1, 11).setValue("Notified");}}
}

Question:
How do I tighten up the code in order to improve its efficiency and stop these errors, or else allow it to stop its run without producing a timeout error report?

How  many loops does it  perform before failing?

I don't see any problems with the code.

I've seen it completely successfully a couple dozen times before failing once.

You could just add a column of checkboxes and when you change it from false to true you send the email if notifiedStatus is not Notified using an installable onedit andremove the loop just do it for the row the checkbox is on.

You should  create a output array and send all data at once. If that is still slow, you have to use sheets api.
function SendEmail2() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Dumbledore requests page');
const rg = sheet1.getDataRange()
const data = rg.getValues();
const subject = "Detention appointment";
const out = [];//Added
for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
const email = data[i][9]; // Email address from Column J
const notifiedStatus = data[i][10]; // Status from Column K
    if (email && !notifiedStatus) { 
      const studentName = data[i][0];
      const teacherName = data[i][3];
      const homeTeacher = data[i][2];
      const message = "Hello " + studentName + ",<br><br>This email is to inform you that you have a detention with one of your professors (" + teacherName + "), during your next free period. Check in with your free period supervisor (" + homeTeacher + ") immediately after your lunch, or your substitute teacher if there is one, then go straight to " + teacherName + "'s room as soon as you're told to do so.<br><br>Thank you.<br><br>Sincerely,<br>the Hogwarts Spreadsheet";
      const replyTo = "dumbledore_a@hogwarts.ed.uk"; // Reply-to email address
     MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: email,
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: message,
        replyTo: replyTo
      });
     out.push(["Notified"]);//Added
   } else { out.push([""]); }
 }
 rg.offset(1, 11, rg.getHeight()-1, 1).setValues(out);//Added
}


Alternative method using Map() and ForEach().

It's best to note that @TheMaster's answer is correct and their recommended step to output everything at once is a good approach for your issue.

Pinpointing where the issue is coming from is a hard task. However, there are times that the cause of the Exceeded maximum execution time has something to do with getDataRange().getValues() because the call takes data from even the last column and row of the spreadsheet, regardless if they're used in the function.
You may change that to something like:
var data = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow() - 1, 11).getValues();

This would let you limit the call and the range to only get data from Columns A through K since that's what's being used in the script. You may also use methods like forEach() and map() because there are times that they're faster than the traditional for loop.

This information is on a case-by-case basis due to the return values of each method.

Here's how the code can be modified using map():
function SendEmail2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Dumbledore requests page');
  var data = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow() - 1, 11).getValues();
  var subject = "Detention appointment";

  data.map(r => {
    var email = r[9];
    var notifiedStatus = r[10];
    if (email && !notifiedStatus) {
      var studentName = r[0];
      var teacherName = r[3];
      var homeTeacher = r[2];
      var message = "Hello " + studentName + ",<br><br>This email is to inform you that you have a detention with one of your professors (" + teacherName + "), during your next free period. Check in with your free period supervisor (" + homeTeacher + ") immediately after your lunch, or your substitute teacher if there is one, then go straight to " + teacherName + "'s room as soon as you're told to do so.<br><br>Thank you.<br><br>Sincerely,<br>the Hogwarts Spreadsheet";
      var replyTo = "dumbledore_a@hogwarts.ed.uk";
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: email,
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: message,
        replyTo: replyTo
      });
      sheet1.getRange(2, 11, data.length).setValue("Notified");
    }
  });
}

Here's how the code can be modified using forEach():
function SendEmail2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Dumbledore requests page');
  var data = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow() - 1, 11).getValues();
  var subject = "Detention appointment";
  var out = [];
  data.forEach(r => {
    var email = r[9];
    var notifiedStatus = r[10];
    if (email && !notifiedStatus) {
      var studentName = r[0];
      var teacherName = r[3];
      var homeTeacher = r[2];
      var message = "Hello " + studentName + ",<br><br>This email is to inform you that you have a detention with one of your professors (" + teacherName + "), during your next free period. Check in with your free period supervisor (" + homeTeacher + ") immediately after your lunch, or your substitute teacher if there is one, then go straight to " + teacherName + "'s room as soon as you're told to do so.<br><br>Thank you.<br><br>Sincerely,<br>the Hogwarts Spreadsheet";
      var replyTo = "dumbledore_a@hogwarts.ed.uk";
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: email,
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: message,
        replyTo: replyTo
      });
    }
    out.push("Notified");
  });
  sheet1.getRange(2, 11, out.length).setValue(out);
}

References:
Map()
ForEach()

Please note that if it's still slow, follow what @TheMaster's said. Use Sheets API.

This solution is an amalgam of the strategies @TheMaster and @Jats PPG used in their responses with a few tweaks of my own to enhance readability and functionality. This code isn't tested so there might be errors:
function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
    if (typeof emailAddress !== 'string') return false;

    return /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/.test(emailAddress); 
}

// This predicate function's second argument uses destructuring assignment to assign names to relevant array values, unassigned values are skipped
function processRow(cellsToUpdate, [studentName,,homeTeacher,teacherName,,,,,,to,notifiedStatus], rowIndex) {
    // tweaked the logic to use a one-line 'guard' instead of a full-on if-else branch
    if (notifiedStatus === "Notified" || !isValidEmail(to)) return cellsToUpdate;
    
    const subject = "Detention Appointment";
    // modified to use template string syntax
    const htmlBody = `Hello ${studentName},<br><br>This email is to inform you that you have a detention with one of your professors (${teacherName}), during your next free period. Check in with your free period supervisor (${homeTeacher}) immediately after your lunch, or your substitute teacher if there is one, then go straight to ${teacherName}'s room as soon as you're told to do so.<br><br>Thank you.<br><br>Sincerely,<br>the Hogwarts Spreadsheet`;
    const replyTo = "dumbledore_a@hogwarts.ed.uk"; // Reply-to email address

    // property name and value are automatically assigned when set using this pattern. 
    MailApp.sendEmail({to, subject, htmlBody, replyTo});
    
    return cellsToUpdate.concat(`R${rowIndex + 1}C11`);    
}

function sendEmail2() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Dumbledore requests page');
    const data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
    const cellsToUpdate = data.reduce(processRow, []);
    
    if (cellsToUpdate.length > 0) {
        sheet1.getRangeList(cellsToUpdate).setValue("Notified");
    }
    
}

